# Twython 403 forbidden error

Tags: twitter, oauth, http-status-code-403, twython

I am trying to do two things:
1) stream data from twitter
2) update my status based on that data

Streaming works fine but every time I try to update my status, I get the a 403 error, forbidden.

I get the same response if I use:

```
twitter.verify_credentials()
```

This is the error message I receive:

```
twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), Your credentials do not     allow access to this resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show more of your code so I can see what could be wrong. But my guess is that you maybe making the same error I did. To update your status you do not need to do this:

```
twitter.verify_credentials()
```

You can use the Access Key and secret from your twitter application to update your own account. But more code will help figure this out.